# I want to know mariaDB EOF

Tags: mysql, mariadb, wireshark, packet

I noticed that there is an EOF called `0xFE` between the query and response values ​​in MySQL packet.

EOF is 4 bytes after the query.

I want to know if it also exists in MariaDB.

If you need to set it up separately, I want to know what it is.

I checked 2 query packets in Wireshark.

Query

1. `SELECT TITLE, SN, CN FROM BOARD`
2. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BOARD`

MySQL

1. [image]
2. [image]

MariaDB

1. [image]
2. [image]

Comment: "I am interested in the binary format of the java JDBC driver's transmitted packets. And the possible differences between MariaDB and MySQL." Such a question is very unusual, could be confused with normal JDBC _usage_. - A @SebastianBrosch improved the question already

Comment: Yor title says EOF, your question says EOL; why 0xFE should be considered an EOL is a mystery; and whatever your question actually is can be answered by consulting the relevant protocol documentation. Unclear and off topic.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it with Eof.

Comment: Is this [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html)?

Comment: I found that mysql has not supported since 7.5.
Is there a way to do this too?     mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/packet-EOF_Packet.html   &&   maria: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/eof_packet/